# ExtJS 4 Ext.application requires

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

This is my folder structure:

- app (folder)

  - controller (folder)
  - model (folder)
  - store (folder)
  - utils (folder)
  - view (folder)
  - Settings.js (file)
- data (folder)
- docs (folder)
- ext-4 (folder)
- resources (folder)
- settigns (folder)

  - Settings.js (file)
- app.js (file)
- file.html (file)

This is my app.js code:

```
Ext.application({
name: 'MyApp'           
,appFolder: 'app'           
,requires: [
        'MyApp.Settings'
]
,stores:['strFichaCredenciales', 'strClientes']
,controllers: [  'ctrlMenuPrincipal'
                ,'ctrlArbolOrganigrama'
                ,'ctrlFichaCredenciales'
                ,'ctrlOfertasComerciales' ]
,autoCreateViewport: true
,init: function() {
        this.splashscreen = Ext.getBody().mask('CArgando aplicacion', 'splashscreen');
}
,launch: function() {
    Ext.getBody().unmask();
if (MyApp.Settings.dsplg)
    Ext.ComponentManager.get('viewDespliegue').show();      
else
    Ext.ComponentManager.get('viewDespliegue').hide();  
if (MyApp.Settings.in18)
    Ext.ComponentManager.get('ComboTraslation').show(); 
else
    Ext.ComponentManager.get('ComboTraslation').hide(); 
}
});
```

This is my Settings.js code:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.Settings', {
singleton: true,
settingKey2: 'settingValue2',
settinglocale: 'es',
(here are more variables)
}
```

In app.js, in requires option I´m loading the Settings.js file that is in the app folder, but i don´t know how to load the one in settings folder intead of the one in app folder.
Both Settings.js files are as the code above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try around with [`Ext.Loader.setPath`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.Loader-method-setPath).

The easiest and standard-conforming way would be to define your settings as `MyApp.settings.Settings` and then use

```
Ext.Loader.setPath('MyApp.settings', 'settings');
Ext.require('MyApp.settings.Settings');
```

Alternatively, you can use [`Ext.Loader.loadScript`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.Loader-method-loadScript) and provide the path and file name.

Comment: Ok,I will try both options.